# What tools and logs can I use to find out why a server in Eclipse will not start

Tags: eclipse, server, adobe

I have an Adobe Experience Manager and Apache server I launch via docker.  So in my Eclipse IDE (version 2019-09 R), I added the server with New -> Server and chose Adobe -> Adobe Experience Manager, and left the defaults (localhost).  I changed a few server configurations, like the port it uses.
When I very first set this up, it all worked OK.  At this point, I created a second workspace, and tried to add the server again there.  This time, the server will not start from Eclipse, it always says

> An internal error occurred during: "Starting Adobe Experience Manager at localhost".
>
> org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64

And the server just says starting forever until I manually disconnect it.
Also, now back in my original workspace, it does the same thing when trying to start that one, which I am fairly sure was working the first time I set it up.

This error is not much to go on, and Google has not been much help.
I have verified that the server is running via the docker dashboard, and by the fact that my localhost has content.
I have tried deleting some of the workspace .metadata folders and .settings files.  And of course I have tried removing and re-adding various things.  Nothing I have tried has helped, but I am not sure what else I can try, since the error message has so little to go by.
Is there something I can check to get more info on what is failing?  Or are there any other steps I  might try?

edit - There are some server startup errors in the logs for the Adobe server in docker, so maybe that has something to do with it?  These are errors that came up before Eclipse is in the picture, from when I start the docker image.

```
*ERROR* [org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedServiceFactory, id=10, bundle=1/slinginstall:org.apache.sling.commons.log-5.0.0.jar]: Updating property org.apache.sling.commons.log.names of configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config.7b669e07-5509-457a-b00f-ae84687ec3ce caused a problem: Category com.adobe.granite.translation.connector.spartan.memsource already defined by configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config.726f8c8b-e62e-43ff-99b5-4a41fcc61183
27.04.2020 11:44:29.246 *ERROR* [CM Configuration Updater (ManagedServiceFactory Update: factoryPid=[org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config])] org.apache.felix.configadmin Service [org.apache.felix.cm.ConfigurationAdmin,15, [org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationAdmin]] [org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedServiceFactory, id=10, bundle=1/slinginstall:org.apache.sling.commons.log-5.0.0.jar]: Updating property org.apache.sling.commons.log.names of configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config.992cdf43-fc20-47ae-b0ea-a0ac320ef795 caused a problem: Category log.access already defined by configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config.a493d0d7-56a4-408b-bec4-64439a324367 (org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationException: org.apache.sling.commons.log.names : Category log.access already defined by configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config.a493d0d7-56a4-408b-bec4-64439a324367)
27.04.2020 11:44:29.252 *ERROR* [CM Configuration Updater (ManagedServiceFactory Update: factoryPid=[org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config])] org.apache.felix.configadmin Service [org.apache.felix.cm.ConfigurationAdmin,15, [org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationAdmin]] [org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedServiceFactory, id=10, bundle=1/slinginstall:org.apache.sling.commons.log-5.0.0.jar]: Updating property org.apache.sling.commons.log.names of configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config.0a55d2a8-0cd6-45b4-a2ec-0142ed64d1ef caused a problem: Category com.x.apps.x already defined by configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config.ab7bfe98-8085-409b-b940-530e62e637ce (org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationException: org.apache.sling.commons.log.names : Category com.x.apps.x already defined by configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config.ab7bfe98-8085-409b-b940-530e62e637ce)
27.04.2020 11:44:29.263 *ERROR* [CM Configuration Updater (ManagedServiceFactory Update: factoryPid=[org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config])] org.apache.felix.configadmin Service [org.apache.felix.cm.ConfigurationAdmin,15, [org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationAdmin]] [org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedServiceFactory, id=10, bundle=1/slinginstall:org.apache.sling.commons.log-5.0.0.jar]: Updating property org.apache.sling.commons.log.names of configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config.93ce6d3a-1ca8-4e3f-ac10-5a3d64bcaee2 caused a problem: Category com.day.cq.polling.importer already defined by configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config.f82ca91b-41cc-4fa3-9e25-329762b59f5a (org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationException: org.apache.sling.commons.log.names : Category com.day.cq.polling.importer already defined by configuration org.apache.sling.commons.log.LogManager.factory.config.f82ca91b-41cc-4fa3-9e25-329762b59f5a)
27.04.2020 11:46:07.468 *ERROR* [FelixStartLevel] ERROR: Bundle '567' Error starting jcrinstall:/apps/acs-commons/install/acs-aem-commons-bundle-twitter-3.17.4.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve com.adobe.acs.acs-aem-commons-bundle-twitter [567](R 567.0): missing requirement [com.adobe.acs.acs-aem-commons-bundle-twitter [567](R 567.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=twitter4j)(version>=3.0.5)(!(version>=4.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[com.adobe.acs.acs-aem-commons-bundle-twitter [567](R 567.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=twitter4j)(version>=3.0.5)(!(version>=4.0.0)))])
```

Comment: Have you looked at the docker and server logs? Is it the same image in both workspaces?

Comment: @nitind It is the same image for both - I just had different workspaces for different projects on the same server.  Nothing new appears in the server logs when I attempt the start from Eclipse, though the servers are already started according to the docker logs. There are some server start errors I have noticed from when I started the server from docker - I will add those to the original post in case they are relevant.

Comment: Just doing a brand new Eclipse install and deleting and downloading the docker containers seems to have fixed it.  I would still like to know how I could have resolved this in my original Eclipse setup.  I tried deleting .metadata and .settings folders/files, was there some other way to try resetting things in the Eclipse install that I already had?